# setmultichoiceitem is not executed in Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

** Emulator is not displaying Multichoice item("Google","Apple","Ms","Samsumg","Nokia")....
It is not executing setmultiitemsselected function
can anyone help me to find out the solution? **

```
   
    ***My Program***

    public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    CharSequence[] items = {"Google","Apple","Ms","Samsumg","Nokia"};
        boolean[] itemcheck = new boolean[items.length];
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog d = null;
            switch (id) {
            case 0:
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ab.setIcon(R.drawable.fb);
            ab.setTitle("Facebook Dialog");
            ab.setMessage("Successfully Logged");
            ab.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            });
      ab.setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemcheck, 
                  new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked? "Checked" :"Unchecked"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
            d = ab.create();
            }
            return d;
        }  }

    ***Xml File***
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the setmultiitemselected function is not executed"?

The easiest way to create an `AlertDialog` would be this:

```
CharSequence[] items = {"Google","Apple","Ms","Samsumg","Nokia"};
boolean[] itemcheck = new boolean[items.length];

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setIcon(R.drawable.fb)
.setTitle("Facebook Dialog")
.setMessage("Successfully Logged")
.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})
.setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemcheck, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int which, boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked? "Checked" :"Unchecked"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
})
.show();
```

Though the array `itemcheck` doesn't make any sense in your current implementation!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setMultiChoiceItems` and `setMessage` cannot be used together.  If you specify a message, then the checkboxes will not appear.